# Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова «говорит» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

*Всё-таки что-то случилось, но он не говорит(,) что именно.*

Answer (score 4):

«Он не говорит(,) что именно» является сложноподчинённым предложением.
Правила допускают оба варианта: с запятой и без неё.

> Если при союзном слове, образующем придаточную часть, имеется частица, то постановка запятой перед ней факультативна: *Я не помню, **что именно**; Он затрудняется сказать, **что ещё**; Эту цитату можно будет найти, я даже помню **примерно где.***

Ориентируясь по этим примерам, я бы выбрал вариант с запятой:
*Всё-таки что-то случилось, но он не говорит, **что именно.***

Если бы частицы ***именно*** не было, то запятая не ставилась бы:
*Всё-таки что-то случилось, но он не говорит **что.***

Источник: [Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136) [справочник Розенталя, пункт 4. 3)].